# Neo4j TransactionEventHandler Relations

Tags: neo4j

I'm using a TransactionEventHandler in Neo4j as a form of trigger. Basically, anytime something updates, I want an event fired. It's work well so far, but I'm having an issue with deleted nodes/relationships.

I know that properties of deleted nodes and relationships have to be collected from removedNodeProperties() and removedRelationshipProperties() respectively. I've got a way to convert those back into the original elements. But how do I get the relationships that these elements had before they were deleted? For instance, if I have a deleted relationship, how do I know which nodes it was connected to before it was deleted? Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, if I have a deleted relationship, how do I know which nodes it was connected to before it was deleted? Or is that not possible?

The startNode and endNode should still be on this relationship, that is how you can determine which nodes belonged to a relationship.

Comment: Ahh, I had a slight logic error. However, it's worth nothing that this information isn't available for nodes, only relationships. However, it's trivial to determine the node information from the relationship information. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it's not worth nothing. Although I have a helper function written, Neo4j forces you to delete relationships before nodes, so when the node is deleted, it actually doesn't have any relationships. No wonder I was so confused.